# is it possible to get a gemspec from a .gem archive?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

This might be really naive as I have never had to do this before but is there a way to generate a .gemspec file from a .gem? Like the opposite of `gem build xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

A .gem file is basically a .tar archive. Inside this .tar archive you will have 2 important files:

- data.tar.gz - containing the source code and possibly a .gemspec file (this is not a guarantee though)
- metadata.gz - basically a .gemspec, but in a YAML format which you won't be easily able to convert back